# Opening a new form using windows form c++

Tags: c++, forms

I'm a new programmer trying to have a multiple form.

I tried to open a new form using a button:

```
{
//This will open the ordering widow
NewOrder^ order = gcnew NewOrder;
order->Show();
//This one is to hide the current form
this->Hide();
```

}

but it gives me an error message says that:

\projects\cppwinform1\cppwinform1\MyForm.h(135): error C2227: left of '->Show' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

\projects\cppwinform1\cppwinform1\MyForm.h(135): note: type is 'unknown-type

where line 135 is order->Show();
Please if someone can help me fixing that, and just open my other form

thnx

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must** include the desired behavior and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please read how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Might you need to put brackets after gcnew's classname?

Comment: Is this an answer or a question/comment?